# How to include an attribute to let the user decide whether to use GPU or not in pytorch?

Tags: python, class, pytorch, gpu

I am a beginner in Python and pytorch, and my apologies for not making myself clear or not using the proper terms.

I am trying to write a linear regression class that would allow the user to decide whether they want to run the model on GPU or not.

The following are my codes in a pretty dumb way.

```
class LinearRegression():
    def __init__(self, dtype = torch.float64):  
        self.dtype = dtype
        self.bias = None
        self.weight = None
        
    def fit(self, x, y, std = None, device = "cuda"): 
        if x.dtype is not self.dtype:
            x = x.type(dtype = self.dtype)
        if y.dtype is not self.dtype:
            y = y.type(dtype = self.dtype)

        #let the user decide whether they want it to be standardized 
        if std == True:
          mean = torch.mean(input = x, dim=0).to(device)
          sd = torch.std(input = x, dim=0).to(device)
          x = x.to(device)
          x = (x-mean)/sd
        u = torch.ones(size = (x.size()[0], 1), dtype = self.dtype).to(device)
        x_design = torch.cat([u, x], dim = 1).to(device)
        y = y.to(device)
        parameter = torch.inverse(
            torch.transpose(x_design, dim0=0, dim1=1) @ x_design).to(device) @ \
                    torch.transpose(x_design, dim0=0, dim1=1).to(device) @ y

        self.bias = parameter[0, 0]
        self.weight = parameter[1:, 0]
        return self
```

Basically I just added .to(device) to every tensor so that it would be run on the device that the user wishes to use.
However, I am sure there is a better way to do this, perhaps including something in the `__int__`?

I am not sure how to make writing it more efficiently so that I don't have to include .to(device) anytime I add a new function.